# How do you copy an array formula down a column in Calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have the following array formula in cell `B2`:

```
=INDEX($M$2:$O$110;MATCH(1;($M$2:$M$110=C2)*($N$2:$N$110=E2);0);3)
```

and I want to copy it down a column, so I want:

`B2 {=INDEX($M$2:$O$110;MATCH(1;($M$2:$M$110=C2)*($N$2:$N$110=E2);0);3)}
B3 {=INDEX($M$2:$O$110;MATCH(1;($M$2:$M$110=C3)*($N$2:$N$110=E3);0);3)}
B4 {=INDEX($M$2:$O$110;MATCH(1;($M$2:$M$110=C4)*($N$2:$N$110=E4);0);3)}`

etc

I enter the formula into `B2`, I press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, then I copy the formula down the `B` column. This only gives me:

```
=INDEX($M$2:$O$110;MATCH(1;($M$2:$M$110=C2)*($N$2:$N$110=E2);0);3)
```

The relative reference to `C2` and `E2` seems to be treated as an absolute reference. I want `E2` and `C2` to change.

I'm using OpenOffice Calc, so I have `;` instead of `,` in the functions.

Comment: Are you typing in cell `B2`, then `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, and then draggin down like a normal formula? Because that would work in Excel. It sounds more like you are highlight the area you want and then pasting the single value which maybe creates a single array formula for the whole region. What you want is a separate array formula in each cell.

Comment: @Dan it works in MS Excel but OP uses OpenOffice Calc - when doing same thing in Calc it does not work.

Comment: @Irina Are you able to delete a single cell after pasting the formula or do you get the error that you can't alter a portion of an array? If you've done it correctly, you should be able to delete a single row as each contains it's own array formula

Answer (score 1):

In Calc (OpenOffice or LibreOffice) you will always create *one* array formula for the whole overlined area if you fill down or sidewards a array formula with the fill handle (small black dot in the bottom right corner of the active cell).

If you need to create single array formulas for each cell, then you have to copy the formula, then select the destination cells and paste the formula.

You can also copy, not fill, if you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging the fill handler.