# The AGGREGATE function is not working as expected

Tags: function, formula, libreoffice-calc

I have a formula that works in Excel, and I thought I had it working in LibreOffice, but I am getting different results between programs. I am dealing with a forum database tens of thousands rows long, so I can't do it manually like I have it here.

I have a table that should look like this (and does in Excel):

```
messageid   threadid    replyto Last messageid in thread
3550        3550        0       3550
3867        3867        0       4677
3947        3867        3867        
3998        3867        3947        
4337        3867        3998        
4414        3867        4337        
4481        3867        4414        
4677        3867        3867        
3925        3925        0         7200
4653        3925        3925        
4959        3925        4653        
7200        3925        3925        
4092        4092        0         4092
5800        5800        0         5800
5802        5802        0         5802
7202        7202        0         7202
7203        7203        0         7656
7294        7203        7203        
7305        7203        7203        
7342        7203        7203        
7406        7203        7342        
7436        7203        7305        
7656        7203        7203
```

I am trying to find the last 'messageid' within a 'threadid'. If the 'replyto' is `0`, then I get a result, if it's not `0`, then blank.

I used this function in Excel with success:

```
=IF(C2=0,AGGREGATE(14,6,$A$2:$A$24/($B$2:$B$24=B2),1),"")
```

In LibreOffice, I get different results using the same function. Instead of the last (largest) number from Column A showing, I get the first number, so it looks like this:

```
messageid   threadid    replyto Last messageid in thread
3550        3550        0       3550
3867        3867        0       3867
3947        3867        3867        
3998        3867        3947        
4337        3867        3998        
4414        3867        4337        
4481        3867        4414        
4677        3867        3867        
3925        3925        0        3925
4653        3925        3925        
4959        3925        4653        
7200        3925        3925    
4092        4092        0        4092
5800        5800        0        5800
5802        5802        0        5802
7202        7202        0        7202
7203        7203        0        7203
7294        7203        7203        
7305        7203        7203        
7342        7203        7203        
7406        7203        7342        
7436        7203        7305        
7656        7203        7203
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Seems as if `Calc` fails to get the `$A$2:$A$24/($B$2:$B$24=B2)` as an array directly within the formula.

The array formula:

```
{=IF(C2=0,MAX(IF($B$2:$B$24=B2,$A$2:$A$24,0)),"")}
```

works in both `Excel` as well as `Calc`.

To enter an array formula in Excel input the formula into the cell without the curly brackets and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. The curly brackets then appear automatically.

To enter an array formula in Calc input the formula inti the cell without the curly brackets. Then open the Function Wizard using the [fx] button. There set the [x] Array button to checked. In Calc don't fill an array formula down using the cell's fill handle since this leads to extending the target array range and not to copy the formula. Instead copy it to clipboard and paste it to multiple target cells.

Comment: I was just getting ready to write the same thing, based on your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25486290/5100564).